# POST login from Postman to Spring Security

Tags: reactjs, authentication, post, spring-security, postman

So we are quite new at programming and we doing a project where we have the backend with Spring Security and the front is going to be in React. I have been trying to send a POST with the username and password to Spring Security but I am stuck, the only returns I get are 401 and 404.

I do not want Spring Security to render a login page I just want to be able to POST and receive a Session and in the end Csrf and userId back.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final RestAuthEntryPoint restAuthEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, RestAuthEntryPoint restAuthEntryPoint) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.restAuthEntryPoint = restAuthEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/api/user/login", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthEntryPoint).and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/user/login");

    }
```

I have noticed that if I remove:

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthEntryPoint)
```

Postman will return the whole html form.

[Postman picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkkX.png)

Answer (score 0):

if we look at your configuration it tells us the following:

```
.antMatchers( "/api/user/login", "/login").permitAll()
```

We have permitted all requests to the endpoint `/api/user/login` and `/login`.

I have no idea what you are doing here, since you have not posted the code for `restAuthEntryPoint`.

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthEntryPoint)
```

And here:

```
.loginProcessingUrl("/api/user/login")
```

You are defining that whatever login form you are using, if it is the spring default one, or your custom written one in react, will `FORM POST` the login information to this defined endpoint.

If you dont want spring to serve you a login page, i suggest you dont `permittAll` on the `/login` page. I have no idea how you are going to host your application, if the spring server will serve your react app on the same host, or if you are going to host the app and the backend on separate servers.

In your react app if you want to login using the defaults you do a `FORM POST` request to `/api/user/login` and `NOT` a json post. Containing two fields a `username` and a `password`. And if successful you will get a `SESSION` cookie back.

i suggest you read in the [official spring security documentation on form login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form) to understand how the flows work. There is actually more to it then i have explained here.